# Why are all my images are showing as question marks?

Tags: image

All my images are showing up as question marks. I can see that it is connected to the right folder. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi3g2.png)

Comment: Can you add a / in front of the location?

Comment: <img src="/images/logo.png"> like this? No it didn't work

Comment: Does the directory  `images` in fact exist in your root `html` directory?  IE `/var/www/html/images` (Or however you have your web server set up).  If it does exist .. Be sure that `logo.png` exists within that directory.  If it does, be sure the CAPITALIZAION is correct.  If that's all good .. There should be no issues.